# Primefaces dataTable sortBy a Date property

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using a `p:dataTable` to display a list of objects and I would like to order them by their Date property in a descending manner here is the code:

```
<h:form id="receivablesForm"> 
    <p:dataTable id="receivablesTable" value="#{receivableManager.overdueReceivables}" var="receivable" rows="18" emptyMessage="#{msg['warning.noData']}" style="width: 585px;" sortBy="#{receivable.dueDate}" sortOrder="descending">
        <p:column sortBy="#{receivable.invoice.number}" styleClass="fixedSizeColumnSmall">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.number']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{receivable.invoice.number}-#{receivable.number}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.clientName']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{receivable.invoice.client.person.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column styleClass="fixedSizeColumn">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.dueDate']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{receivable.dueDate}" style="#{receivableManager.isOverdue(receivable) ? 'color: red' : ''}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['label.amount']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{receivable.amount}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" locale="pt_br" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

However the objects are not being ordered at all. Is it possible to order by a Date property in a descending manner using the sortBy and sortOrder properties?

Comment: Why don't you get data as sorted from database?

Comment: @ Ömer Faruk Almalı I could, but I want to know if it is possible to do it this way.

Comment: Default sortBy and sortOrder for dataTable has issue which is not solved yet, please checkout https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=457